# Running through a column in excel and removing certain text based on a vlookup

Tags: vba, excel, loops, vlookup

I apologize in advance if this is trivial but I am struggling to remember the syntax for visual basic as it has been so long.

I have text in cells in column D that needs removing (Country names). I have a separate sheet that contains all the Country names and so I thought I could run through the column cell by cell and check whether there were any cells whose text matched that of the country table I have on a separate sheet. (I.e. a vlookup which changed the text if it matched to something like 'deletME')

Thanks!

Comment: [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) will get you started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution that uses an array instead of a range. Just plug in the country names to the array as needed:

```
Sub deletingcountries()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Integer

Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

Dim countries As Variant, country As Variant
countries = Array("Country1", "Country2", "Country3", "Country4", "Country5") 'add however many countries necessary

For i = 1 To lastrow
    For Each country In countries
        If InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value, country) Then
            ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value = "deletME"
        End If
    Next country
Next i
End Sub
```